# Making world geometry with Ogre3d

Tags: geometry, ogre, levels

In [Ogre3d's manual](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_9.html#The-Mesh-Object) and in [the documentation](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_mesh.html#details) it's said that Ogre::Mesh shouldn't be used for world geometry. Quoting the manual:

> Mesh objects are assumed to represent movable objects and are not used
>   for the sprawling level geometry typically used to create backgrounds.

So how *do* I make world geometry? This feel like an oversight where the authors assumed that the answer was obvious, but I really can't find it. Googling questions like "how do I make a cube?" or "how do I make a room with walls and a floor?" leads me to answers that boil down to "Use your SceneManager to generate a surface mesh, then build walls and stuff with it" which strike me as extremely tedious and inefficient.

tl;dr What is the simplest, recommended way to make static non-file-based geometry in Ogre3d?

Comment: Create meshes, put them into entities and put those into static geometries.

Comment: I'm aware of this possibility; but as I said, the official sources seem to be consistently against this approach (see the quote above). Maybe it *is* the best or the only solution, and the official documentation is simply wrong.